# WPF Adorner not drawn when AdornedElement is not visible

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I derived a adorner with custom ArrangeOverride function that takes care of the placement and the size of the containing ContentPresenter.

If the element is visible when the page is rendered the first time every thing works fine. But if the adorned element is not visible at that time (for example in the not shown part of a ScrollPanel) the adroner is never drawn even then the panel scrolls down and the element gets visible.

```
protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
{
    Rect adorneredElementRect = GetBounds(AdornedElement);  
    ...
}
```

In this cases adorneredElementRect is Empty and my calculation will fail.

The adorner is attached to a textbox by a Behavior.

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<TextBox> {
   ...

   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
        myAdorner = new MyAdorner(AssociatedObject);
        var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(VisualHelper.GetTopAdornerLayer(AssociatedObject));
        layer.Add(myAdorner);

        base.OnAttached(); 
  }
```

How can I force the call of ArrangeOverride  when the element gets visible ?

Comment: Does the constructor ensure there's an element to be adorned?

Comment: Yes, it's ensured otherwise it would throw an exception